# VirtualBox VM doesn't restart after blackout

Tags: virtualbox

I can't make my VirtualBox VM manually restart after a blackout (it was running before the power went off).

This is the error I get:

```
vbox@chebasti:~/VirtualBox VMs/DockerRegistry$ VBoxHeadless --startvm "DockerRegistry" -e "TCP/Ports=4444"
Oracle VM VirtualBox Headless Interface 4.0.4
(C) 2008-2011 Oracle Corporation
All rights reserved.

Error: failed to start machine. Error message: UUID {20afee16-bf06-43c4-ab02-770106ce3498} of the medium '/home/vbox/VirtualBox VMs/DockerRegistry/ubuntu-14.04-server-amd64-disk1.vdi' does not match the value {4c6a8bcb-3766-4581-9f45-0de031c65c95} stored in the media registry ('/home/vbox/.VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml')
```

I already tried to search the error online and tried to follow different instructions but none worked.

You can find the output of `VBoxManage showvminfo DockerRegistry --details` [here](http://pastebin.com/4bnFDAXB) (I did not pasted it here because it is very long).

The output of `VBoxManage showhdinfo ubuntu-14.04-server-amd64-disk1.vdi` is:

```
vbox@chebasti:~/VirtualBox VMs/DockerRegistry$ VBoxManage showhdinfo ubuntu-14.04-server-amd64-disk1.vdi
UUID:                 4c6a8bcb-3766-4581-9f45-0de031c65c95
Accessible:           no
Access Error:         UUID {20afee16-bf06-43c4-ab02-770106ce3498} of the medium '/home/vbox/VirtualBox VMs/DockerRegistry/ubuntu-14.04-server-amd64-disk1.vdi' does not match the value {4c6a8bcb-3766-4581-9f45-0de031c65c95} stored in the media registry ('/home/vbox/.VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml')
Logical size:         0 MBytes
Current size on disk: 0 MBytes
Type:                 normal (base)
Storage format:       VDI
Format variant:       dynamic default
In use by VMs:        DockerRegistry (UUID: 952200e9-db58-420a-8fe1-ef49523def3d)
Location:             /home/vbox/VirtualBox VMs/DockerRegistry/ubuntu-14.04-server-amd64-disk1.vdi
```

**UPDATE**

I don't know if it is of any use but here you are the output of `VBoxManage showhdinfo \{4d495022-b596-47c0-8f38-f16c6c5d7f63\}.vdi`:

```
vbox@chebasti:~/VirtualBox VMs/DockerRegistry/Snapshots$ VBoxManage showhdinfo \{4d495022-b596-47c0-8f38-f16c6c5d7f63\}.vdi 
UUID:                 4d495022-b596-47c0-8f38-f16c6c5d7f63
Accessible:           yes
Logical size:         0 MBytes
Current size on disk: 564 MBytes
Type:                 normal (differencing)
Storage format:       VDI
Format variant:       differencing default
In use by VMs:        DockerRegistry (UUID: 952200e9-db58-420a-8fe1-ef49523def3d)
Location:             /home/vbox/VirtualBox VMs/DockerRegistry/Snapshots/{4d495022-b596-47c0-8f38-f16c6c5d7f63}.vdi
Auto-Reset:           off
```

Answer (score 1):

Just leaving a reply for future (unlucky) people.

I couldn't find a solution and even on the [VirtualBox forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=63086&p=296307) anybody could help me. I reinstalled the machine.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem with my boot2docker VM after running low on power on my macbook.

`$ boot2docker start -v
Using virtualbox driver
2014/09/04 18:00:42 executing: VBoxManage showvminfo boot2docker-vm --machinereadable
2014/09/04 18:00:42 executing: VBoxManage startvm boot2docker-vm --type headless
Waiting for VM "boot2docker-vm" to power on...
VBoxManage: error: UUID {0caf9f04-5159-403a-828c-0dd9be68e1a0} of the medium '/Users/-/VirtualBox VMs/boot2docker-vm/boot2docker-vm.vmdk' does not match the value {07ad4be9-d2d0-4ac5-bb8a-e992e816ed19} stored in the media registry ('/Users/-/Library/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml')
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component Medium, interface IMedium`

What seemed to fix it for me was to "boot2docker stop", remove the .vmdk from VirtualBox Storage settings, run this command (mentioned in http://www.vleeuwen.net/2012/10/virtualbox-uuid-mismatch):

`VBoxManage closemedium disk ~/VirtualBox\ VMs/boot2docker-vm/boot2docker-vm.vmdk`

then reattach the disk and "boot2docker start".